# In my example, comma or no comma before the word respectively?

Tags: commas, sentence-ends

> In the graph for all arrests, and DUI arrests, the effect of the MLDA is about 125 and 50 increase in arrests rate respectively.

I personally think no comma should be put before the word *respectively*. And what about the comma before the phrase *and DUI arrests*? Should I remove it? I want to say there is one graph for each and make that clear.

So maybe I should change the first part of the sentence to something like:
.

> In both graphs for all arrests and DUI arrests, the effect of the MLDA is about a 125 and 50 increase in arrests rate respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one comma is required in the sentence, and that is after *DUI arrests*. The phrases *all arrests* and *DUI arrests* make up a coordinated complement of the preposition *for*, and a comma would only serve to separate them. The final word *respectively* is an integral part of the clause in which it occurs, and should not be separated from the rest of it.